# Summing area of by several attributes in QGIS

Tags: qgis, features, area, grouping, summarizing

I have a shapefile that contains building footprints with multiple addresses with different functions (with each an usable area). I would like to calculate the sum of the usable area, per building `"id"`, per same `"function"`, as such:

| id | function | area |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | wo | 10 |
| 1 | wi | 2 |
| 2 | wo | 50 |
| 1 | wo | 10 |

↓ calculate sum (area) when same id and same function

| id | function | area |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | wo | 20 |
| 1 | wi | 2 |
| 2 | wo | 50 |

I tried to use the following expression:

```
sum(expression [,group_by] [,filter])
```

But the `group_by()` is only possible once (for instance to group the `"id"`).

How can we calculate the sum of the two features only when these have the same `"id"` and same function?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is also a possibility using a ["Virtual Layer"](https://docs.qgis.org/3.10/en/docs/user_manual/managing_data_source/create_layers.html#creating-virtual-layers) through `Layer > Add Layer > Add/Edit Virtual Layer...`.

Let's assume there is a point layer called *"test"* with its attribute table, see image below.

[image: input]

With the following query, it is possible *to calculate the sum of the features only when these have the same `"id"` and the same `"function"`*, as well as getting rid of duplicates.

```sql
SELECT
    SUM(value) AS sumvalue,
    COUNT(*) AS numgrouped,
    "id" || "function" AS grouped,
    geometry AS geom
FROM
    "test"
GROUP BY
    "id", "function"
```

The output point layer with a new attribute table will look like

[image: result]

Last but not the least, *keep in mind that:*

- the number of features in the final output will be less (rarely the same) than in the original shapefile
- grouping values of features with neglecting their geometries is not the same as the grouping values of features with preserving their geometries

Comment: great, that works - thank you!

Answer (score 6):

Use a combination of the two fields like concat: `"id" || "function"` for the `group_by()` part of the expression:

```
sum("area", "id" || "function")
```

Comment: Great, that works thank you!